# Load all record when reset collection for magento admin form grid

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid

I have grid which have collection if i choose to reset it gives only joined or mapped record so when i select reset button on grid it should be display all record without filtering. My code is as below.

```
     <?php
class Freedom_Shippinggroup_Block_Adminhtml_Shippinggroup_Edit_Tab_Formcustomer extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('customerGrid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true); // Using ajax grid is important
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultFilter(array('customer_ids'=>1)); // By default we have added a filter for the rows, that in_products value to be 1
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);  //Dont save paramters in session or else it creates problems
        $this->setAdditionalJavaScript("
        // added click on selectbox support
        serializerController.prototype.rowClick = serializerController.prototype.rowClick.wrap(function(o, grid, event) {
            var tagName = Event.element(event).tagName
                isSelect = (tagName == 'SELECT' || tagName == 'OPTION');
            if (!isSelect) {
                o(grid, event);
            }
        });
        ");
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        // Set custom filter for in product flag
        if ($column->getId() == 'customer_ids') {
            $customersIds = $this->_getSelectedCustomers();
            if (empty($customersIds)) {
                $customersIds = 0;
            }
            if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in'=>$customersIds));
            } else {
                if($customersIds) {
                    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('nin'=>$customersIds));
                }
            }
        } else {
            parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
        }
        return $this;

    }

    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $groupId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id',array('in' => array(5)));
    $collection->getSelect()->join( array('shippinggroupcustomer'=> 'shippinggroupcustomer'), 'shippinggroupcustomer.customer_ids = e.entity_id and shippinggroupcustomer.shippinggroup_id='.$groupId,array('shippinggroup_id','customer_ids','shouldsendwarrantymail','shouldsendfactorymail','shouldsendordermail'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}



    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('customer_ids', array(
            'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
            'type'              => 'checkbox',
            'name'              => 'customer_ids',
            'values'            => $this->_getSelectedCustomers(),
            'align'             => 'center',
            'index'             => 'entity_id'
        ));


        $this->addColumn('shouldsendwarrantymail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendwarrantymail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendwarrantymail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Warranty Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));

        $this->addColumn('shouldsendfactorymail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendfactorymail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendfactorymail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Factory Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));
        $this->addColumn('shouldsendordermail', array(
            'name'              => 'shouldsendordermail',
            'index'             => 'shouldsendordermail',
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Should Send Order Mail'),
            'type'              => 'select',
            'options'   => array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false


        ));


        $this->addColumn('name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
            'index'     => 'name'
        ));
        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
        ));

        /*$groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('group', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'width'     =>  '100',
            'index'     =>  'group_id',
            'type'      =>  'options',
            'options'   =>  $groups,
            'filter'    => false,
        ));*/


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row) {
        return false;
    }

    protected function _getSelectedCustomers()   // Used in grid to return selected customers values.
    {
        $customers = $this->getSelectedCustomers();
        return $customers;
    }

    public function getSelectedCustomers()
    {
        // Customer Data

        $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if(!isset($tm_id)) {
            $tm_id = 0;
        }

            $custIds = array();
            $customerProductIds = Mage::getModel('shippinggroup/shippinggroupcustomer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('shippinggroup_id', array(
                     array('finset' => $tm_id)));
                    // print_r($customerProductIds->getData());
            foreach($customerProductIds as $id){
                $custIds[$id->getCustomerIds()] = array(
                                                        'shouldsendwarrantymail' => '1',
                                                        'shouldsendfactorymail' => '1',
                                                        'shouldsendordermail' => '1'
                                                        );
            }

        //var_dump($custIds);exit;
        return array_keys($custIds);
    }

    /**
     * Rerieve grid URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/customergrid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you rewrite any code class in this module ?

Comment: no nothing was rewrite

Comment: Can you put your full code of this file here with class name and extends.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is wrong :

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $store = $this->_getStore();
    $groupId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('group_id',array('in' => array(5)));
    $collection->getSelect()->join( array('shippinggroupcustomer'=> 'shippinggroupcustomer'), 'shippinggroupcustomer.customer_ids = e.entity_id and shippinggroupcustomer.shippinggroup_id='.$groupId,array('shippinggroup_id','customer_ids','shouldsendwarrantymail','shouldsendfactorymail','shouldsendordermail'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($collection->getData());die; // to print all data
    echo $collection->getSelect(); die; // to print query
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: not working dear :(

Comment: I thing i m near to solve this can you please help me on this. i have changed join `$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft` instead of join now it will give all the collection record on load instead of just selected.

Comment: It will only show this collection which you are getting from this collection. To check your data and query you can print_r($collection->getData()); here.

Comment: whenever you are using `join` it will work as inner join, and when you used `joinLeft` it will work as left join.

Comment: everything is going fine now but one new problem here when i reset filter and save it remove all previous entry.because when it reset i think serialize input is set to null do you know about this?